# How to get the first letter of each word in SQL

Tags: sql

I tried to run this query to get the initial letter of each word, and it worked for strings of 4 words, yet if the string has only two words, it duplicates the second word's initial.

```
select
  substring(column_name, 1, 1) + 
  case 
    when 0 <>  charindex(' ', column_name) + 1
      then substring(column_name, charindex(' ',column_name) + 1, 1)
    else ''
  end +
  case 
    when 0 <>  charindex(' ', column_name, charindex(' ', column_name) + 1) 
      then substring(column_name, charindex(' ', column_name, charindex(' ', column_name) + 1) + 1, 1)
    else ''
  end + 
  case
    when 0 <> charindex(' ', column_name, charindex(' ', column_name, charindex(' ', column_name) + 1) + 1)
      then substring(column_name, charindex(' ', column_name, charindex(' ', column_name, charindex(' ', column_name) + 1) + 1) + 1, 1) 
    else '' 
  end

from table_name
```

Comment: Can you please share input and expected output?

Comment: Which dbms? You could consider unnest, string-to-array, string-to-table or similar functions to assist in splitting the words then taking the first byte from each unnested value.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which RDBMS you are using.  This should work in SQL Server:

```
drop table if exists table_name

create table table_name (
  column_name varchar(255)
)

insert table_name
values ('See Jane')
     , ('See Jane run')
     , ('See Jane run and jump over the lazy dog.')


select stuff((SELECT '' + t2.fc
from (
    select left(str.value, 1) fc
    , charindex(' ' + str.value + ' ', ' ' + t.column_name + ' ') idx
    from string_split(t.column_name, ' ') str
) t2
order by t2.idx
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 0, '') as FirstChars
from table_name t
```

The `idx` column is used to order the ouptut because `string_split` does not promise to return the results in any particular order.  Thanks to Aaron Bertrand - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/string-split-and-ordered-results

Answer (score 0):

Given the use of charindex in your question, I'm assuming you are using SQL Server. The CTE generates a tall view of your data using `string_split` function, with each letter on it's own row. We then select from it and group by id, and apply the `string_agg` function to place back into a single row.

Password guessing?

```
create table my_data (
  id integer, 
  comments varchar(50)
  );

insert into my_data (id, comments) values 
(1, 'Thank goodness its friday'), 
(2, 'I want 2 scoops of ice cream');

select * from my_data;
```

| id | comments |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Thank goodness its friday |
| 2 | I want 2 scoops of ice cream |

```
with cte (id, first_char) as (
  select id, substring(ss.value, 1, 1) as first_char
  from my_data
  cross apply string_split(comments, ' ')ss
  )
select t.id, 
  string_agg(t.first_char, ',') as letters_delimited, 
  string_agg(t.first_char, '') as letters_not_delimited
from cte t
group by t.id
```

| id | letters_delimited | letters_not_delimited |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T,g,i,f | Tgif |
| 2 | I,w,2,s,o,i,c | Iw2soic |

[fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/LPwqIuOb)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your approach with recursion

```
WITH cte_name AS (
    select CONVERT(nvarchar(max), substring(column_name, 1, 1)) conc, 
           column_name n, 
           charindex(' ', column_name, 0) pos 
    from table_name

    UNION ALL 
    select conc + substring(n, pos + 1, 1) as conc, 
           n, 
           charindex(' ', n, pos + 1) pos 
    from cte_name where pos > 0
)
 
SELECT *
FROM  cte_name
where pos = 0;
```